# Размытый фон div

Tags: css, css3

Как реализовать blur эффект фона `div` элемента, чтобы он подстраивался под background body.

Вот пример
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а где вы взяли пример? Это просто фото или с какого-то сайта скриншот? Если с сайта - может ссылку дадите на него?)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Взята картинка с сайта Apple в разделе бета тестирования iOS. Если бы сайт у них был готов, вряд-ли бы сюда писал))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Есть не суперкроссбраузерная, но рабочая штука, css-свойство filter

```css
div {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/800/people/3/);
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  position: relative;
}
div> div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: transparent;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/800/people/3/) -300px 500px;  
  left: 300px;
  top: 300px;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<div><div></div></div>
```

Подробнее здесь - https://webref.ru/css/filter
Ну и спецификации - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp

Answer (score 2):

Также можно попробовать использовать blur.js - http://blurjs.com/

А можно и такое решение - http://www.quasimondo.com/BoxBlurForCanvas/FastBlurDemo.html

Но опять таки, IE9+